# Moving to Nth table row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help.

How can I at the click of a button, move to the next row in my table. The concept is this, once a table row, in the table body is selected via a mouse click, the table row then changes background color and a row number is recorded. I'd like to use the given row number to move to the next table row and essentially "click it" as I would with a mouse, at the click of a button.

To keep things as simple as possible, i'd like to use jQuery.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<style type="text/css">

.highlight {

    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);

}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

var row

    $("#data tbody tr").click(function() {

        var selected = $(this).hasClass("highlight");

        $("#data tr").removeClass("highlight");

        if (!selected) { $(this).addClass("highlight"); }

        row = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex

        $("#rownum").val(row)


    });



}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header1</th>
            <th>header2</th>
            <th>header3</th>
            <th>header4</th>
            <th>header5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
Row Number:
<br>
<input type="text" id="rownum" readonly>

<input type="button" id="goto_next" value="next">


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can use `$('table tr').eq(index)` the index in this case starts at 0. So 0 for 1st row, 1 for 2nd row, 2 for 3rd row, etc.

Comment: It doesn't move the highlighted row to (index), matter a fact I don't see anything happening at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extract highlighting functionality into separate function and use it from both click handlers:

```
var $tbody = $("#data tbody").on('click', 'tr', function() {
    highlight($(this));
});

$('#goto_next').click(function() {
    var $next = $tbody.find('.highlight').next();
    highlight($next);
});

function highlight($row) {
    if ($row.length) {
        $tbody.children().removeClass("highlight");
        $row.addClass('highlight');
        $("#rownum").val($row[0].rowIndex);
    }
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wygRe/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/yktqf/

```
$("#goto_next").on("click", function(event) {
    var $table = $("#data"),
        $selectedRow = $("tbody tr.highlight", $table);
    $selectedRow.insertAfter($selectedRow.next()).removeClass("highlight").click();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, pull the TR click handler into a separate function, and add another function that gets attached to the click event on the goto_next button. From there pull the current selected row value from the text element, increment it and fire that into the select_row function.

```
function next_row() {
    var elem = $('#data')[0].rows[parseInt($('#rownum')[0].value) + 1];
    select_row(elem);
}

function select_row(elem) {
    var selected = $(elem).hasClass("highlight");
    $("#data tr").removeClass("highlight");
    if (!selected) { $(elem).addClass("highlight"); }
    row = $(elem).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex
    $("#rownum").val(row)
}

window.onload = function() {
    var row;
    $("#data tbody tr").click(function(){ select_row(this) });
}
```